# Exibir os 5 primeiros números diviseis por 3, descartando o numero 0

Tags: c, algoritmo, operadores, controle-de-fluxo

Não estou conseguindo exibir os 5 primeiros divisíveis por 3, coloquei uma variável contador, mas ela retorna outro  número.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 20;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if(i%3 == 0)
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alguém poderia me explicar como?

Comment: Esta exibindo os números `3 6 9 12 15 18`, vc quer exibir somente os `3 6 9 12 15`?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. os 5 primeiros.

Comment: Opa-  aproveite para ver nas respostas os estilos de indentação do código. É __muito__ importante indentar corretamente todas as linhas - ajuda você e os outros a lerem o seu próprio código de forma bem mais fácil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para exibir os 5 primeiros números basta contar a quantidade de números divisíveis por 3, quando a quantidade for igual a 5 encerra o loop, veja o exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cont = 0, numero = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        numero++;

        if (numero % 3 == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", numero);
            cont++;
        }

        if (cont == 5)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> 3
>   6
>   9
>   12
>   15

Comment: Entendi como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar uma flag para verificar se já imprimiu todos os 5 primeiros números.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 20;
    int flag = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if(i%3 == 0) {
            flag++;
            printf("%d\n", i);
            if(flag == 5)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu já tentei desse jeito, e não funciona.

Comment: Você tentou errado, acabei de executar esse programa e funcionou.

Comment: Sim, funcionou agora, a ordem esta errada.

Comment: Só um comentário, Renato, que não tem a ver com a sua solução - em geral chamamos (e damos o nome de) "flag"  à variáveis que contém um significado de "verdadeiro" ou "falso". Nesse caso, a variável mantém uma contagem, então o melhor mesmo seria um nome como "counter".